# backup microsoft SQL server 2008 to OneDrive

Tags: sql-server-2008, onedrive

Is there an option to automate a backup to Microsoft Onedrive every night?
The machine is a Windows server 2008 R2
I would like to to able to automatically upload my backups to OneDrive. I was wondering if there is an option to do so automatically.

If its not possible, how about naming the backup files by date each time its backups and just dropping the backups in a OneDrive folder

And is there a difference between SKyDrive and OneDrive?

Thank you

P.S.
I decided on OneDrive because its the cheaper cloud I know for now 1TB for $6.99 a month. And soon they will introduce the unlimited plans.

Comment: SkyDrive *became* OneDrive (IIRC, it was LiveDrive before that)

Comment: ...and it will probably have a different name next week. Microsoft Azure Drive is my guess.

Comment: You can simply make scheduled SQL Server backups and send them to OneDrive with the help of https://sqlbak.com

Answer (score 0):

No problems. I use Handy Backup, which contains both MySQL and [OneDrive](http://www.handybackup.net/onedrive-backup.shtml) plug-ins to fully automate the job.

The greatest problem you can expect is too fast expiration of your free storage space on OneDrive.